# JSONPath filter not working on nested json that contains nested object instead of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jsonpath

I'm looking for a way to filter this JSON and retrieve only the cost when fid > 10

Working example, the `parent` prop is an array:

```
 [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "properties": {
            "parent": [
                {
                    "fid": 10,
                    "cost": 100
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "properties": {
            "parent": [
                {
                    "fid": 20,
                    "cost": 200
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 32,
        "properties": {
            "parent": [
                {
                    "fid": 30,
                    "cost": 300
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

JSONPath = `$[*].properties.parent[?(@['fid']>10)].cost`

```
result = [
  200,
  300
]
```

Not working example, the `parent` prop is now an object:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "properties": {
            "parent": {
                "fid": 10,
                "cost": 100
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "properties": {
            "parent": {
                "fid": 20,
                "cost": 200
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 32,
        "properties": {
            "parent": {
                "fid": 30,
                "cost": 300
            }
        }
    }
]
```

JSONPath = `$[*].properties.parent[?(@['fid']>10)].cost`

The result is `No match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$[?(@.properties.parent.fid>10)].properties.parent.cost
```